# Writing a base64 string to file in python not working

Tags: file, base64

I am getting a base64 encoded string from a POST request. I wanted to store it in my filesystem at a particular location after decoding . So i have written this code,

```
try:
   file_content=base64.b64decode(file_content)
   with open("/data/q1.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(file_content)
except Exception as e:
   print(str(e))
```

This is creating the file at /data/ but the file is empty. It is not containing the decoded string. There is no permission issue.
But when i am instead of file_content writing 'Hello World' to the file. It is working. Why python is not able to write base64 decoded string to the file? It is not throwing any exception also. Is there something i need to take care when dealing with base64 format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This line returns byte:

```
file_content=base64.b64decode(file_content)
```

Running this script in python3, it returned this exetion:

write() argument must be str, not bytes

You should convert bytes to string:

```
b"ola mundo".decode("utf-8")
```

try it

```
import base64

file_content = 'b2xhIG11bmRv'
try:
   file_content=base64.b64decode(file_content)
   with open("data/q1.txt","w+") as f:
        f.write(file_content.decode("utf-8"))
except Exception as e:
   print(str(e))
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But will it also work if encoded string also contains image.

Comment: the images are bytes so when you save it it will also have to be bytes, I think you did not need to use the decode. But you will have to open your file as a byte writing mode. in the open case ("data / q1.jpg", "wb")

Answer (score 2):

As a previous answer said, `f.write()` expects bytes. You don't need to convert to a string, however. You can write the bytes directly

```py
import base64

file_content = 'b2xhIG11bmRv'
try:
   file_content = base64.b64decode(file_content)
   with open("data/q1.txt","wb") as f:
        f.write(file_content)
except Exception as e:
   print(str(e))
```