# MemoryError while decoding with base64 for large files

Tags: python

I am trying to decode string which is stored in a file. The file size is around 300 MB. It's throwing MemoryError while decoding.

```
base64.b64decode(bytes(file_content))
```

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a base64 string to file in python not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651409/writing-a-base64-string-to-file-in-python-not-working)

Comment: Side-note: Why the `bytes` wrapping? When decoding, `b64decode` accepts both `str` and bytes-like objects of any type, which means the `bytes` conversion is either wrong, does nothing, or unnecessarily copies 300 MB of data (because it was some bytes-like thing that you just forced it to copy).

Comment: @prashantrana: That question is wholly unrelated; this is a `MemoryError`, not a `TypeError` due to mismatched `str`/`bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data isn't already `bytes`, you've just forced an unnecessary copy to make a true `bytes` object. Annoyingly, it looks like `base64.b64decode` will perform this unnecessary conversion for you for all inputs aside from `bytearray`, even though the underlying API (`binascii.a2b_base64`) properly supports the buffer protocol (so it works just fine on, say, mmapped files).

So if you want to avoid an unnecessary copy, change to:

```
binascii.a2b_base64(file_content)
```

which decodes without copying the input at all.

The other general tip is to make sure you're running a 64 bit build of Python (the default suggested installer for Windows is still 32 bit, sadly). When you're talking hundreds of MB of data, with copies of it floating around, it's pretty easy to hit the 2 GB limit on user mode virtual address space, and upgrading to 64 bit Python will fix that for you (your code might be slow if you don't have enough RAM for it, but it shouldn't die from a `MemoryError` so easily).